# How do I escape backticks in a comment?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I want to be able to post this as a comment:

> FYI, code [formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) is done with backticks, e.g. `` `sudo vi /boot/grub/menu.lst` ``.

But as you can see, it doesn't come out quite right...

Comment: FYI, code [formatting](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) is done with backticks, e.g. `` `sudo vi /boot/grub/menu.lst` ``.

Comment: Use "\\`" for a \` to be shown.

Comment: FYI, code formatting is done with backticks, e.g. `\`sudo vi /boot/grub/menu.lst\` `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use (inside backquotes) `` \`sudo vi menu.lst\` `` for a `` `sudo vi menu.lst` `` to be shown.

Comment: I had the same problem too, and found out how to do it by reading the markdown manual.

Comment: @Lekensteyn What manual are you referring to? I was mislead by [this documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), which explains: "To include a literal backtick character within a code span, you can use multiple backticks as the opening and closing delimiters."

Comment: The page you are referring to, but section [Backslash escapes](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash).