# How do I escape backticks in a backticks command?

Tags: discussion, support, answer-format, markdown, formatting

I found: "[How do I escape backticks in a comment?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1056/how-do-i-escape-backticks-in-a-comment)", but I want to escape backticks, if I use backticks to format code in an answer.

The following doesn't work:

```
`sudo update-initramfs -v -u -k \`uname -r\``
```

The result is this:

`sudo update-initramfs -v -u -k \`uname -r``

Desired goal, but with using backticks:

```
sudo update-initramfs -v -u -k `uname -r`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following (without four spaces):

```
``sudo update-initramfs -v -u -k `uname -r` ``
```

generates the desired goal:

`` sudo update-initramfs -v -u -k `uname -r` ``

**Source:** [How can the backtick character ` be included in code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70679/195083)

Answer (score 2):

You can indent code by four spaces instead of using a backtick.

```
`hey everybody`
```

For more information:

- [How do I escape a backtick in Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-to-escape-a-backtick-in-markdown)

Comment: I know, I used it in my question.

Answer (score -1):

Note: This answer is somewhat off topic as it doesn't directly answer the question; however I believe that it adds value/info so I'm posting.

Use of backticks e.g. `` `...` `` is the legacy (non-POSIX compliant) BASH method of command substitution. As a rule `$(...)` should be used instead. It's POSIX compliant and there are a ton of other good reasons! For most of them see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts